# mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, sd-card

We are trying to port Linux to a custom board designed based on the Evaluation Board by Renesas. The kernel source, DTB and File systems are booted through SD card.

While booting  Kernel image, Dtb and file system are read from the SD card but the boot log shows the following error.

```
    [    2.850008] renesas_sdhi_internal_dmac ee100000.sd: Tuning procedure failed
    [    2.879075] mmc0: tuning execution failed: -5
    [    2.883480] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
    [    2.980220] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
    [    2.986483] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL16G 14.8 GiB 
    [    2.993043] mmcblk0: p1
```

We are able to login to the linux console. We had to disable all the other sdhi, fot the linux to boot from sdhi0(mmc0).